# Is KB4056759 part of Meltdown and spectre update fix?

Tags: windows-update, meltdown, spectre

I can't tell if it is part of Meltdown and Spectre. MS site says its a fix for "An elevation of privilege vulnerability exists in the Microsoft Server Message Block (SMB)".

But a couple of sites link this update as if its part of it.

Here is a link to [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/7o5si5/psa_severe_vulnerabilities_in_fundamental_cpu/)  and 
[a screenshot of another site.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVTi8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't tell if it is part of Meltdown and Spectre. MS site says its a fix for "An elevation of privilege vulnerability exists in the Microsoft Server Message Block (SMB)".
>
> [image]

There is a mistake in the chart.  The vulerability that [KB4056759](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4056759/security-update-for-vulnerabilities-in-windows-server-2008) resolves is connected to CVE-2018-0749 which is not one of the Meltdown/Spectre vulnerabilities.  However, CVE-2018-0749 is indeed one of the vulnerabilities, fixed by the current Security Update.

[image]

[Source](https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-us/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2018-0749)

> An elevation of privilege vulnerability exists in the Microsoft Server
> Message Block (SMB) server when an attacker who has valid credentials
> attempts to open a specially crafted file over the SMB protocol on the
> same machine. An attacker who successfully exploits this vulnerability
> could bypass certain security checks in the operating system.
>
> The update addresses the vulnerability by correcting how Windows SMB
> Server handles such specially crafted files.
>
> To learn more about the vulnerability, go to [CVE-2018-0749](https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-us/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2018-0749).

The reason people are mistakenly making a connection, to the Meltdown/Spectre patch, is because (CVE-2017-5753, CVE-2017-5715, and CVE-2017-5754) are included in the same cumulative patch that includes [KB4056759](https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-us/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2018-0749).  In other words, [CVE-2018-0749](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4056759/security-update-for-vulnerabilities-in-windows-server-2008), is included in [KB4056892](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4056892/windows-10-update-kb4056892)(Windows 10 Version 1709).  [There are only three vulnerabilities associated with Meltdown/Spectre](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/microsoftsecure/2018/01/09/understanding-the-performance-impact-of-spectre-and-meltdown-mitigations-on-windows-systems/) anyways.

Comment: My answer is written from the perspective of a Windows 10 machine.  `KB4056759` is a Windows Server 2008 patch, so the monthly cumulative and/or security only patch model should be applied.